# Battery charger schematic review

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have designed this circuit to charge a 7.2V battery (linked below), and I just want to make sure I did not miss anything before I go an get it manufactured.

[image]

My main questions are:

1. will that PFET I chose work, or do I need something with different parameters (Ids, Vgs, etc.)?
2. the battery voltage is 7.2V, but the datasheet says it has a charge voltage of 8.4V - will the IC I chose still work in that case?

Battery I am using: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jauch-quartz/LI18650PBF-2S1P-PCM-WIRE/9560970

Charger IC: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/MCP73844-840I-MS/593751?s=N4IgTCBcDaILIGEAKB2AzADgCxYLTYAYBJAejgGUQBdAXyA

Comment: Have you read the datasheets carefully? Especially the one for the battery, which clearly says that the charge voltage is 8.4 V? The battery datasheet also says "nominal voltage" when mentioning 7.2 V. (That just means that the voltage, halfway from full charge to discharge, will be 7.2 V; a little low, perhaps, compared to some.) I suppose also especially the IC datasheet since it also has a nice, long section on FET selection. Have you gone through it with some calcs, yet?

Comment: Note that the actual spec of ceramic capacitors is critical. 10uF isn’t necessarily 10uF! Read up on dc bias derating. PCB layout is also critical.  Understand where the current is flowing.

Comment: @jonk, yes I did do all of that, I just wanted to double check my work

Comment: What would happen if the battery was connected in reverse? Is this likely? What if the linear pass fet went short circuit?How about connecting the 12V the wrong way?And what about spikes on the 12V input getting into the chip?